# ImagePullBackOff error - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, docker-image, self-signed-certificate

We try to pull an image from a private docker registry and deploy it in Kubernetes master-node. Here, we get the 'unknown certificate authority' error message. Also, in the pod side, we get the status as `ImagePullBackOff`.

For your information, we have generated a self-signed certificate for the private docker registry and copied it in the kubernetes hosts in the following path.

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/private_regsitry_domain:port/ca.crt
```

Additionally, the `daemon.json` is configured to accept "private_registry_domain" as an insecure registry. We are able to push and pull to the private registry through Docker, while k8s pods fail to do so.

How to make the kubernetes nodes to accept the self-signed certificate to work with private registry?

It would be more helpful if anyone could help us in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy your pod using kubectl create --insecure-skip-tls-verify -f pod.yml

Comment: Also, try to do docker pull from each node, not just from the master node.